# Why won't this work with jQuery 1.9?

Tags: jquery

So, I wrote a small bit of jquery to toggle a side-bar on my web app, and it works just fine in jQuery 1.8, but once I upgraded to 1.9, it broke. Here is the code:

```
$('a#sidebar-act').toggle(function() {
    $('div#sidebar').animate({width:260}, 200);
}, function() {
    $('div#sidebar').animate({width:64}, 200);
})
```

Comment: There's quite a bit that's changed between 1.8 and 1.9. Have a look through the [upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/). You can also use [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) plugin to detect compatibility issues within your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality of the `toggle` method [has been removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed). You'll have to track the toggle yourself:

```
var alternateMethod = false;

$('a#sidebar-act').click(function() {

    $('div#sidebar').animate({
        width: alternateMethod ? 64 : 260
    }, 200);

    alternateMethod = ! alternateMethod;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this bit. I'm not sure why they removed toggle, as it made my life easier, haha, but I'm sure I'll manage without it.